# JQuery Timer Countdown different times on weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code for a daily timer set to countdown to 3pm PST everyday.

```
function makeTimer() {

    //      var endTime = new Date("29 April 2018 9:56:00 GMT+08:00");  
            var endTime = new Date(today + " 15:00:00");            
            endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

            var now = new Date();
            now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

            var timeLeft = endTime - now;

            var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400); 
            var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60);
            var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));
  
            if (hours < "10") { hours = "" + hours; }
            if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "" + minutes; }
            if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "" + seconds; }

            $("#days").html(days + " <span>Days</span>");
            $("#hours").html(hours + " <span>Hours</span>");
            $("#minutes").html(minutes + " <span>Minutes</span>");
            $("#seconds").html(seconds + " <span>Seconds</span>");

    }

    setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); }, 1000);
// End
```

I need to be able to give it a different target time for Saturday and Sunday, each days need to be different.

```
Saturday Timer end is 1:00PM PST
Sunday Timer end is 12:00PM PST
```

How can I achieve this with the script above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the `Date.getDay()` method to determine the current day of the week where 0 = Sunday, and 6 = Saturday

Comment: thank you, i am not familiar with coding, how would i implement that into the current code? could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function updateTimer(timeLeft) {
    var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400);
    var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

    if (hours < "10") {
      hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < "10") {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < "10") {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    $("#days").html(days);
    $("#hours").html(hours);
    $("#minutes").html(minutes);
    $("#seconds").html(seconds);
  }

  function makeTimer() {
    var endTime = new Date();
    switch (endTime.getDay()) {
      case 0:
        if (endTime.getHours() >= 12) {
          endTime.setDate(endTime.getDate() + 1);
        }
        endTime.setHours(12, 0, 0);
        break;
      case 6:
        if (endTime.getHours() >= 13) {
          endTime.setDate(endTime.getDate() + 1);
        }
        endTime.setHours(13, 0, 0);
        break;
      default:
        if (endTime.getHours() >= 15) {
          endTime.setDate(endTime.getDate() + 1);
        }
        endTime.setHours(15, 0, 0);
    }
    var now = Date.now();
    return Math.floor((endTime - now) / 1000);
  }

  $(".timer").data("interval", setInterval(function() {
    var tl = makeTimer();
    console.log(tl);
    if (tl <= 0) {
      clearInterval($(".timer").data("interval"));
    } else {
      updateTimer(tl);
    }
  }, 1000))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">
  <span id="days"></span> Days <span id="hours"></span> Hours <span id="minutes"></span> Minutes <span id="seconds"></span> Seconds
</div>
```

Best practice is to break things down into small easily repeatable steps or functions. With the number of Seconds left, we can update and display the timer. That just leaves the step  of calculating the seconds left between now and a specific time.

When I check the day, if it's Saturday (`6`) or Sunday (`0`), we have unique times. The default is then set if it's not.

Comment: This work beautifully except for one issue. Every time the timer hits it's end time, for the next hour it doesn't display anything. So like on a weekday, when the timer needs to reset at 3pm, from 3 to 4pm the timer doesn't display anything. Is there something we can do about this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll look at it. Suspect it's related to the endTime hour matching for that hour.

Comment: @aBe adjust the logic in the Switch to `>=` instead of `>`.  This way if time is 2:59pm, it will show 1 min, if time is 3:01pm, it should 0 days, 23 hours, 58 min...